# Uploading Images in vuforia Engine

Tags: android, augmented-reality, vuforia

> Invalid file format. Only 8 bit gray scale or 24 bit RGB of file type JPG or PNG are allowed.

Actually I'm trying to upload image target in vuforia engine database but this show me like this. I'm already uploaded lots of images in vuforia engine but past one weeks I receive this type of errors in more cases.

How to upload any type of images in vuforia engine?

Answer (score 1):

The error message states exactly the problem. It seems like the image you are trying to upload is either not .jpg/.png or not 24bit RGB. I am assuming the latter.

Anyways, simply convert your image to 24bit .png or .jpg online for example.

Comment: you can use software like GIMP https://www.gimp.org/ to check the image color coding and convert it to the desired 24bit format